# Trouble with lookup columns

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-form

So we have a site collection.  And in that site collection there is a sub site.  On the sub site we have a form that was created in Infopath.  This form connects to many other lists using lookup columns for selections.  We were able to export the list from this site to another it worked well.  The lookup columns display the correct information and the other lists got exported as well and display all their info just fine.

The issue is that after filling the form out, the data that I select in the list column doesnt save in the list itself.  I get no errors filling the form out and such.  Is there anything that can cause this issue?

Comment: You should open the InfoPath form and update the Submit connection to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the submit option on your list is not working correctly (in that case only save/submit option on the form does not give any error but the data won't get saved on the list). Customize your list and make sure your submit button is connected properly.

Comment: Ahh im sorry, i forgot to mention, for some reason this form only has a save button. There is no submit button. I was not the original author of this form. Soy you think it could be the save button on the top ribbon? Edit: Also the fields with text in them save. It is just the Lookup columns.